# Xamarin Forms HTML editor

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm looking for a HTML editor to that can be used in a Xamarin Forms Project. I need both an iOS and Android implementation. Another option is to try and shoehorn one of the existing open source projects in to a custom forms control. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry but I'm voting to close this. It is way too broad, you are looking for some resource and you didn't show any effort as to find something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is the "TEditor": https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/TEditor

Never tried but it does look good (though i dont know if its still in active developement)